# Update a web page without reloading the whole page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Youtube does not reload entire page to navigate between pages. How to use that navigation scheme?

Do I need to use Javascript or do I need an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called ajax load. It probably uses an API in the background, but you do not need to and it is a Javascript technology.

Here is a primer for ajax [Ajax tutorial by W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using `AJAX` by sending `XMLHttpRequest`to browser.
Better see full code: [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first)

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things to achieve it:

1. Use of ajax, update your dynamic part with the help of jquery or similar technology.
2. Use of iframes, update your dynamic parts by changing iframe source. Youtube itself uses iframes to load many multiple parts parallelly and dynamically.